# For parameter find the number of solutions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We have $\begin{cases} x^3-3xy^2-tx=-2\\3x^2y-y^3-ty=2\end{cases}$

for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ determine the number of points $(x,y)=(x(t),y(t))\in \mathbb{R^2}$ which satisfy our system of equations

I find that $\displaystyle y=\frac{-3x}{(tx-4x^3+1)^2}$ and if we find the number of solutions of $\displaystyle x^3-\frac{27x^3}{(-tx+4x^3-1)^2}-tx=-2$ we will get the answer.

Comment: To begin with: if $t=0$, then $x=y$ satisfies the system.

Comment: @Kuifje but only when x=y=1. I checked some cases in wolfram and hypothesis is that there is 3 solutions for all $t$